# Return specified number of words before and after given position in text

Tags: java, regex, words

I have a BIG problem with the following code. I would expect it to return n number of words before and after the found keyword (needle) but it never does.

If I have a text, say

```
"There is a lot of interesting stuff going on, when someone tries to find the needle in the haystack. Especially if there is anything to see blah blah blah".
```

And I have this regular expression:

```
"((?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,5}\b)needle(\b(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,5})"
```

Should this NOT exactly match needle in the given string and return the text as

```
someone tries to find the needle in the haystack. Especially if
```

It never does :-( On execution, my method always returns an empty string, although I definitely know, the keyword is within the given text.

```
private String trimStringAtWordBoundary(String haystack, int wordsBefore, int wordsAfter, String needle) {
    if(haystack == null || haystack.trim().isEmpty()){
        return haystack ;
    }

    String textsegments = "";

    String patternString = "((?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,"+wordsBefore+"}\b)" + needle + "(\b(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,"+wordsAfter+"})";


    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(haystack);

    logger.trace(">>> using regular expression: " + matcher.toString());

    while(matcher.find()){
        logger.trace(">>> found you between " + matcher.regionStart() + " and " + matcher.regionEnd());
        String segText = matcher.group(0); // as well tried it with group(1)
        textsegments += segText + "...";
    }

    return textsegments;
}
```

Quite obvious, the problem lies within my regular expression, but I can't figure out what is wrong with it.

Comment: It doesn't look like you made provision for whitespace characters within the expression, usually you would use `\s` in the place where you have `\b` and also present within the character classes preceding/following it...  Something like `"((?:[\w'\.-]+\s){0,"+wordsBefore+"})"` and similar for the after...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is basically fine, but in Java you need to escape the `\b`:

```
"((?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,5}\\b)needle(\\b(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,5})"
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but does `\\b` actually account for whitespace?  I thought there would also have to be a `\\s` present...

Comment: \b is the word boundary meta-character, so it matches a little bit more than spaces.

Comment: Okay, but doesn't there then have to be two boundaries for each separation between words?  `\\b` doesn't actually match all the possible whitespace between two words does it, since it is specified as a "zero-width match"?

Comment: It does eat all the possible whitespace between two words. I think that is exactly what is meant with it being a zero-width match.

Comment: Haha, yeah, that's programming for you. We've all been there.